# getBoundingClientRect() not giving expected results

Tags: javascript, dom, height

When logging the height of an element I get a different value to what is displayed.

Here I am logging the height of the element rect and the actual element details to the console.

```
const slideHeight = slides[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;

console.log(slideHeight);
console.log(slides[0]);
```

Why are the two height values different. How can I grab the correct height value?[image]

Comment: See the documentation for [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) on how height and width are calculated.

Comment: Ok that's not helpfull. Even if I log the clientHeight, offsetHeight and scrollHeight, they all show 401 and not 673. How can I get the correct value?
console.log(slides[0].clientHeight);
console.log(slides[0].offsetHeight);
console.log(slides[0].scrollHeight);